# How to create video file from DVD

Tags: dvd, encoding, ripping, handbrake, idvd

I want to take the DVD video slideshow that I got from my wedding photographer, and put the video on youtube (I have permission, I made sure to get the non-exclusive rights to use anything she created while working for me in any way I wanted when we working out the terms before-hand).

Can anyone suggest the best way to get a video file that can be uploaded to YouTube from this DVD?  The source DVD is not encrypted, so I don't need to worry about that.  I am using a Mac, so Mac-friendly suggestions are preferred.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** So, I tried Handbrake, and it looks very promising.  However, When I select the title in Handbrake, it says it is about 12 minutes long.  The resulting file ends up only being about 4 minutes long, and the music is messed up.  It seems to be going normally through the photo transitions, but removing the time that the slideshow stays on each photo.

I believe the DVD was created using iDVD.  Does it do anything weird to save space by varying hte framerate, or anything like that? Are there special settings in Handbrake I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the current version of VLC allows you to record the DVDs you could give that a try.

Comment: VLC ended up working very nicely.  Handbrake's output ended up getting screwed up in that it seemed to drop frames when the picture in the slideshow was static (for a couple seconds).

Comment: Good stuff, I've found handbrake very good with normal DVD's particularly for portable devices but I've never tried picture DVD's.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool I've found to rip a DVD to a video file is [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/).  You have the choice of what part to rip, what format to rip to, etc.  The resulting video should be easily uploaded to the video site of your choice.

Comment: Thanks, that was coming up in some Google searches too. I tried it though, and it wasn't getting the whole video. It would just show a single photo transition into another photo, and then end. The video ended up being about 2 seconds long, instead of 12 minutes. Any ideas?

Comment: Of course, that could be because I'm using OS 10.4, so I'm using the old, unsupported version of handbrake. Maybe I should try with my work laptop, which runs 10.5...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Handbrake get good reviews.
My own favorite is imgburn at http://www.imgburn.com/.
Also take your pick as the need may arise among :

- AutoGK at http://www.autogk.me.uk/
- DVD Decrypter at http://www.dvddecrypter.org.uk/
- SimpleDivX at http://www.free-codecs.com/download/SimpleDivX.htm
- RipIt4Me at http://www.videohelp.com/tools/RipIt4Me